# How to make AJAX requests in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class UserList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(' https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          data: result.data,
        });
      },
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
   <div>
    {data.map(datalist => (
      <p>
      {datalist.id} - {datalist.name} - {datalist.year} - {datalist.color} - {datalist.pantone_value}
      </p>
    ))}
   </div>
```

only the products between these brackets are appear. Just like this.

```
 {
  items: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Apples', price: '$2' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Peaches', price: '$5' }
  ] 
}
```

but I can not show the products between these brackets. Example : 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
 [
  { id: 1, name: 'Apples', price: '$2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Peaches', price: '$5' }
 ]
```

How can I do that. Thank you.

Comment: use `data: result,`

Comment: Sorry i dont understand :/

Comment: The data from this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts is already an array, so use `data:result` in your `setState`

Comment: i could not.I edited the question, hope you understand.

Comment: Do you want to call two seperate endpoints? Can't understand your question, your code works fine for me and displays all the items from  https://reqres.in/api/unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the data from the end point `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` You just need to use the response instead of response.data, as the endpoint is sending the array directly instead of wrapping it in a data key.

You need to change your setState to

```
     this.setState({
          data: result,
        });
```